# How to Trigger total number of days in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, input, triggers

"I need to create a field that will show the number of days between a date and the present.

```
TABLE:  reg_add

+------------+---------+
| Name       | Type    |
+------------+---------+ 
| hm_date    | date    |
+------------+---------+ 
| total_days | date    |
+------------+---------+
```

My client will type in the following date for example in "hm_date":  May 1, 2012.

I need "total_days" to show the total days between May 1, 2012 at the current date.

I want to achieve this on server-side, which is somewhat new to me.

I need to create a **TRIGGER** to always have "total_days" updated

I started with this and I'm having trouble making a trigger and getting it correct:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(curdate(),hm_date) as total_days FROM reg_add
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Erik

Comment: Why is `total_days` of type `date`?

Comment: Another member recommended it to me.  The client will always type his/her date in the following format: "June 23, 2008"

Comment: I thought `hm_date` was the field containing the client input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik, I am using tsql, and not as familiar with mySQL, but in tsql the `DATEDIFF` function requires 3 parameters. The sytax is

> `DATEDIFF(date part, date1, date2).`

I would try `DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),hm_date) AS total_days FROM reg_add`

Comment: His SQL works perfectly for getting the days in MySQL.  As he said, he need to create a "Trigger" to always have total_days updated.

Comment: Also, RedFilter's question on your original post is an important one. The output of DATEDIFF is going to be an INT type value of the number of days between the two. No need to try to create a variable DATETIME type as a place holder.

Comment: "hm_date" (the client input & field) need to be what type?

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what he means by "Trigger". The select statement will return the correct value for the date difference every time it is called.

Comment: The "total_days" field will always appear to the client in a search result and various forms as a result.  Is it possible to setup a trigger on server-side and not be concern with a php script on the client-side?

Comment: @Erik, both date arguments of the DATEDIFF call need to be DATETIME. So hm_date needs to be DATETIME, and of course curdate() output will be DATETIME. What does NOT need to be date time is the total_days. The output of DATEDIFF() will always be an integer. No placeholder variable need be pre-defined unless you are trying to capture the output. In that case, it would need to be an INT type for the total_days.

Comment: I guess this is where I would need to know the bigger picture. What are you trying to make happen client side? So, they type in a date, then what? Are they clicking submit and you are grabbing the date, calculating the difference and storing it in the DB, or are you trying to capture it as soon as they type in and dynamically return the number of days to the client to modify something on their display?

Comment: Is it not possible to always have "total_days" updated every hour or so on the server-side?  or do I have to cron it on the client side in a php script?

Comment: The client creates a record with a date (hm_date).  Whenever the client does a search query and selects this record in different forms, I need "total_days" to always appear updated.

Comment: okay, I think I had a light bulb go off. I now realize you are talking about static data already stored and keeping it up to date... Okay, yeah, that is not going to work. You wouldn't want to store the actual total_days at all. There is no way for it to continually upate (aside from a SQL job on your server). The best implementation would be to calculate the DATEDIFF realtime as you call the data. You could write a small stored procedure to populate a temp table or something with the data you need, including the total_days, and call that with your code.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to make this a php routine on the page its displayed on.

Comment: Erik, though I would not recommend the SQL job because it isn't a clean solution, and it can definitely eat up resources depending on how big your tables are, I also understand that sometimes you gotta make it happen. Suggestion 1: make the calculation in your client side code (best if you can) 2:Go ahead and store the total_days in DB as you mentioned, write a small stored proc like UPDATE reg_add SET total_days=DATEDIFF(curdate(),hm_date), then set up a SQL Server job to run the code every morning. If the number of tables is huge, it could take a while to execute. Not best, but may work.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate it on the fly very easy, using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function -

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hm_date, NOW()) FROM reg_add;
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look into the MySQL Trigger Docs and from the looks of it, you can only create trigger for event types Insert, Update, and Delete.  So your Trigger won't actually update your total_days field (which should be int) as you want it. [It sounds like you want it to update your field on a time basis (aka every x hours update)].

Here is the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

I would suggest writing a cron job in php that runs once (or multiple times) per day that will update the field for you.

In your cron you should just have to run one sql statement:  (This should go through the whole table and update the total_days field for each row)

```
UPDATE reg_add SET total_days = DATEDIFF(curdate(),hm_date)
```

Comment: So if the client does a search query, I can add this this php script to the search query.  Yes?

Comment: No. If this is the route you would want to go, i would suggest making a Cron Job on your web server.  However from the sound of your last comment, why not just do the datediff in your sql? how are you doing the search and using the total days?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggers, you could use a View:

```
CREATE VIEW reg_add_with_total_days_VIEW
  AS
SELECT hm_date
     , DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), hm_date ) AS total_days
FROM reg_add ;
```

Then you can use the view, every time you need the total days - which will be calculated on the fly:

```
SELECT hm_date, total_days
FROM reg_add_with_total_days_VIEW
```

You can see it working in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc6b3/7)